# TW-EAV510 modem exposes admin interface publically

Tags: router, modem, adsl

I have a ADSL/VDSL modem, model TW-EAV510 ADSL2+/VDSL2 WLAN Router. The firmware version I am running is 5.00.59g-1.

I noticed that the modem is exposing the admin web interface on port 80 via my public IP address. This wasn't a major problem, because I have a pretty strong password, but I'd like to disable this so that the admin interface is only accessible within my local network.

I'm now hosting a website, so I forwarded port 80 to my server. When I set up the port forwarding, the modem automatically mapped the public admin interface to port 8080 (and informed me in an alert box). I have a domain name pointing to my IP, so the admin interface can be accessed through mydomain.com:8080

I've read all the manuals and docs, and combed through every setting in the web interface, but couldn't find any option to disable public accessibility.

Anyone else run into this problem, or know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spoke with a very informative tech support rep from the manufacturer of the modem, and he informed me that I have nothing to worry about. I was accessing my admin interface with my public IP address while I was within my network, so there was an internal loopback which took me to there. If I had tried to access the admin interface from outside the network with my public IP, it would not have show me anything, because there loopback would not happen.